# using cereal and boost serialisation in the same program

Tags: c++, boost, cereal

We currently have a system that uses a *lot* of boost serialisation to store data. We are looking to migrate away from this, to using cereal instead.

However, it is very unlikely that we will be able to completely migrate all serialised objects. At the very least, we will have to be able to de-serialise old version of the data.

Is it possible to use both boost and cereal to serialise the same object, preferably without having to write the serialisation function twice?

An example of our code is:

```
class Base
{
public:
    std::string m_VarA;
    std::string m_VarB

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & rArchive, const unsigned int nVersion)
    {
        rArchive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_VarA);
        rArchive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_VarB);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    std::bitset<32> m_Flags;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & rArchive, const unsigned int nVersion)
    {
        rArchive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base); 
        rArchive & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_Flags);        
    }    
};

std::ostringstream stream;
Derived var;
{
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive rArchive(stream);
    rArchive & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Configuration", var);
}
```

I don't think we have anything much more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb and say "Yes".

The libraries have similarity, but if they don't coexist that would be BUG in either or both libraries.

You don't show ANY code, so we don't know ANYTHING about *how* you organized your serialization code.

For any approach I can envision migration paths.

The most important thing to realize is that the actual serialization code needs only be visible at the point where serialization occurs. If you limit that to TU and make all the functions involved in it file-static, you'll be safe from the sharks¹.

Obviously, you'll be better off if the serialization code was non-intrusive². But even if you do, just make the intrusive method relay to free functions that can be file-static.

### Holy Grail: Unified Serialization Functions

This would require more work, obviously, but seems doable with a modicum of meta programming. From a quick look it looks like it's easier to implement Boost-serializability from existing Cerial serialize functions, but I guess that's tough luck.

---

¹ sharks like ambiguous overloads or ODR violations

² /ɪnˈtruːsɪv/ adjective 1. causing disruption or annoyance...

Comment: I was hoping there would not be any obvious issues. I've added a code sample, so you can see roughly how we do it.

Comment: Oh that's introducing quite a few nooks & crannies. NVP, base-class etc. If I were you I'd simply get down and write the Cereal style serialization. It'll quickly become clear what part can be automated. If you want to cover  absolutely every base, you could cheat and implement a custom archive type that forwards to Cereal. That might not fit the bill, but again, nobody told me anything about ***why*** you iwsh to move over to Cereal, so maybe it _does_ fit the bill. You decide.

Comment: Our major reason for moving away from boost, apart from cereal being shinier, is that its XML serialisation is very delicate. Occasionally, we have to edit the XML directly, and most of the XML tools tend to generate valid XML that boost cannot process.

Comment: Boost has no XML library, and the XML archive backend merely _uses_ XML (a subset). You don't control the archive format any more than with Text or Binary archives. Does Cereal let you control that? (In that case, certainly just handwrite the serialization code so you can leverage that control)